# Selenium get value from Unicef material-ui currency TextField

Tags: c#, reactjs, selenium, xpath, webdriverwait

I need to verify a value which is in "Unicef material-ui currency textfield".
I use bellow code to get the value within the textbox but the value is empty.

```
var value = driver.FindElement(By.Id("txtCurrency")).Text;
```

If you inspect the input field in bellow sample, you can see even though text is visually displayed, "**value**" HTML **attribute** is empty.

HTML snapshot:

[image]

HTML:

```
<input aria-invalid="false" type="text" class="MuiInputBase-input MuiOutlinedInput-input jss493 jss561 MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedStart" value="">
```

Sample URL as bellow : https://unicef.github.io/material-ui-currency-textfield/#currencytextfield
I would like to know a way to get the value/text of input textbox.

Project is in ReactJs and Selenium is in C#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The desired element is a [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) enabled element so you have to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `ElementToBeClickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- *XPath* and `GetAttribute("value")`:

  ```
  Console.WriteLine(new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20)).Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(By.XPath("//h6[text()='Outlined']//following::div//input[contains(@class, 'MuiInputBase-input')]"))).GetAttribute("value"));
  ```

Answer (score 2):

To get the **value** from **input** field you need to use `.GetAttribute("value")`

Use following `xpath` to identify the element.

```
var Value =driver.FindElement(By.XPath("//h6[text()='Outlined']/following::input[1]")).GetAttribute("value");
Console.WriteLine(Value);
```

---

Or following `css selector`

```
var Value =driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector(".MuiInputBase-input.MuiOutlinedInput-input.jss134.jss202.MuiInputBase-inputAdornedStart.MuiOutlinedInput-inputAdornedStart")).GetAttribute("value");
Console.WriteLine(Value);
```

Comment: but @KunduK 'value' is empty in the HTML code when check from browser inspector element view.                                              GetAttribute("value")  won't work since there's no value for 'HTML value' attribute ?

Comment: @shalinds : The value is generated by java scripts that's the reason it is empty. Copy my code and run it and let me know how this goes..